# Matching String for Debug and Release Build in Rust

Tags: rust

Assuming I have an `&str` named `myvar` which I somehow get from environment variables. I can match it as below:

```rust
match myvar {
    "foo" => todo!(),
    "bar" => todo!(),
    _ => todo!(), // if an unexpected value
}
```

I also can know if the compiled app is debug or release build via `cfg!(debug_assertions)`.

Now, what I want is provide a fallback value for this `&str` but it should differ whether the binary is a debug build or not. So:

```
match myvar {
    "foo" => todo!(),
    "bar" => todo!(),
    _ && cfg!(debug_assertions) => todo!(), // fallback in debug build
    _ => todo!(), // fallback in release build
}
```

Is such a thing possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The thing you're looking for is likely to be the [match guards](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch18-03-pattern-syntax.html#extra-conditionals-with-match-guards). General syntax for them is as following:

```
match value {
   pattern if conditional = todo!(),
   // other branches
}
```

In your case, this is a simple change:

```
match myvar {
    "foo" => todo!(),
    "bar" => todo!(),
    _ if cfg!(debug_assertions) => todo!(), // fallback in debug build
    _ => todo!(), // fallback in release build
}
```

Comment: Although in this case I would probably use a regular `if` in the fallback case: `_ => if cfg!(debug_assertions) { todo!() } else { todo!() }`